# Create an image with gradient effect from code with help Core graphics?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create multiple images for button states(normal, highlighted) with gradient effect from code.
I found after searching on net some articles but nothing conclusive.
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: [Need some help googling?](https://www.google.de/search?q=coregraphics+draw+gradient)

Answer (score 2):

This is a great tutorial with exactly what you're looking for:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/36341/paintcode-tutorial-dynamic-buttons

I don't think it gets much more conclusive than this.